# TCPDF gives error when parameter is included in view: CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, tcpdf

I'm trying to create a PDF through view in CodeIgniter. It's working fine for plain HTML but when I try to add a parameter in the view, it gives me this error: **`preg_match_all() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given`**

Here's the content of my controller:

```
$order_data = $this->BOE_Model->get_ordercomplete_items($id);
$view_data = array('order_data' => $order_data);

if($order_data[0]['is_forward_air'] == 1){

    $this->load->library('Pdf');
    ob_start();
    $pdf = new Pdf(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, 'mm', 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);
    $pdf->setUserName('Forex AirDrop Label');
    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
    $pdf->SetTitle('Forex AirDrop Label');
    // set default header data
    $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING, array(0,64,255), array(0,64,128));
    $pdf->setFooterData(array(0,64,0), array(0,64,128));

    // set header and footer fonts
    $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
    $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

    // set default monospaced font
    $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

    // set margins
    $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
    $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

    // set auto page breaks
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

    // set image scale factor
    $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

    // set default font subsetting mode
    $pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);

    // Set font
    // dejavusans is a UTF-8 Unicode font, if you only need to
    // print standard ASCII chars, you can use core fonts like
    // helvetica or times to reduce file size.
    $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 14, '', true);

    // Add a page
    // This method has several options, check the source code documentation for more information.
    $pdf->AddPage('P', 'A4');

    // set text shadow effect
    $pdf->setTextShadow(array('enabled'=>true, 'depth_w'=>0.2, 'depth_h'=>0.2, 'color'=>array(196,196,196), 'opacity'=>1, 'blend_mode'=>'Normal'));


    $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10, '', true);

    $html = $this->load->view('partners/pdf/forward_air', $view_data);
    $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
    $path_to_pdf = 'assets/pdf/airdrop-'.$id.'.pdf';
    $pdf_name = 'airdrop-'.$id.'.pdf';
    $pdfdoc = $pdf->Output($path_to_pdf, "FI");
    ob_end_flush();
}
```

And my view content:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.js'); ?>" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/partners/connectcode-javascript-code128auto.js?v='.VER_NO); ?>" ></script>
<?php
    $counter = 0;
    foreach($order_data AS $get_order):
        $ctyloc = $get_order['City'].(strlen($get_order['Locality']) > 0? ', '.$get_order['Locality']:'');
        $drs = $get_order['AddressLine'].' '.$ctyloc.', '.$get_order['State'].', '.$get_order['ZipCode'];
?>
<table style=" margin-bottom: 10px;" >
    <tr>
        <td style=" padding-left: 0px;" class="fx-content" >
            <img alt="Forexcargo" src="http://forexcargo.us/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Forex-Cargo-Website-Logo.png"><br>
            <div style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top:10px; line-height: 110%;">
                <label class=c_name><?php echo $get_order['buName']; ?></label>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<label class="lname"><?php echo $get_order['Name_Long']; ?></label><br>
                <span class="address1"><?php echo $get_order['buAddress1']; ?></span><br><span class="address2"><?php echo $get_order['buAddress2']; ?></span><br>
                <span class="email-phone"><?php echo $get_order['buEmail'].' '.$get_order['buPhone']; ?></span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;" class="rc-content" >
            <div style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top:50px; line-height: 110%;">
                <label class=c_name><?php echo $get_order['FirstName'].' '.$get_order['LastName']; ?></label><label class="lname"></label><br>
                <span class="address1"><?php echo $drs; ?></span><br>
                <span class="email-phone"><?php echo $get_order['Email'].' '.$get_order['Phone']; ?></span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
    if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1){
            bcode = DrawHTMLBarcode_Code128Auto('<?php echo $get_order['BoxNumber']; ?>',"yes","in",0,5,0.75,"bottom","left","","black","white");
        } else {
            bcode = DrawHTMLBarcode_Code128Auto('<?php echo $get_order['BoxNumber']; ?>',"yes","in",0,4,0.75,"bottom","left","","black","white");
        }
    $('div.for_barcode_<?php echo $counter; ?>').html(bcode);
</script>
<div class="for_barcode_<?php echo $counter; ?>" style="width:5in;"></div>
<?php
    $counter++;
    endforeach;
?>
```

I tried doing the content directly in the controller but I can't find a way to include a javascript file so I decided to stick to using view. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

By Observation, I found that you have to pass boolean value TRUE as third parameter.
 $html = $this->load->view('partners/pdf/forward_air', $view_data,TRUE);